# Calculate percentiles of angles/bearings in Python

Tags: python, descriptive-statistics, quantiles, circular-statistics

I have a dataset with a variable that is the angle of the event (record) from a central point (e.g. crime events in relation to a defined city center). I want to calculate percentiles for the variable. With circular data, the issue is that 1 and 359, for example, are different by a value of 2, not 357.

There are a number of useful posts on circular statistics on Stack Exchange about certain topics in circular or directional statistics and while I have found calculating the median, I have not found how to calculate percentiles

Can someone please make a recommendation for calculating percentiles of angles/bearings? My end goal would be to calculate the set of crime events and group them into quantiles.

Comment: It is indeed possible to calculate quantiles on circular data. In python, your best bet is the recent port of the [CircStats package](https://github.com/circstat/pycircstat), I believe. 

With crime data, be careful that the distribution might be multimodal, which may make the quantiles less sensible.

Comment: It is unclear what a quantile of circular data might possibly mean.  The concept simply doesn't apply to the empirical distribution.  Thus, it is crucial that one fit some kind of distribution that somehow (artificially) supports quantile computation.

Comment: If almost any direction can occur in the data, I would say back off. But I can imagine percentiles working in some situations, if you have (a a very strong concentration near the vector mean (b) a very large gap opposite. Then rotate to have origin opposite the vector mean and calculate as usual. (That may be what the first answer is also proposing.)

Answer (score 0):

If some angular region has very few crimes, you can start from an angle there.

E.g. Consider crime in Chicago, and its angle relative to the center of Chicago’s street [grid](https://www.chipublib.org/blogs/post/not-lost-thank-edward-brennan/) at Madison & State.

[image]

The angles with the fewest crimes are due east of the center, where there is little land.

The bearings in the original data probably go between

- 0 for north
- 90 for east
- 180 for south
- 270 for west
- 359 for just west of north

Adding 360 to some of those numbers gives a new scale going between

- 90 for east
- 180 for south
- 270 for west
- 359 for just west of north
- 360 for north
- 449 for just north of east

This replaces the bearings at 1 and 359 with new bearings at 361 and 359, which are close both numerically and geographically. So the crimes on Lake Shore Drive and in Lincoln Park will show up close together.

Since the new scale is smooth in the regions where the crimes are concentrated, the quantiles derived from it will be sensible.

Comment: You propose adding 360 to half of the values?

Comment: I propose adding 360 to the values between 0 and whatever angle has a minimum number of crimes in its region. For Chicago that would mean adding 360 to the values from 0 to 90 or so, so about a quarter of the values.